# Add a user's message input in an already existing embed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a game system where you can join a game by typing a `"join"` command. But can't think of a way to take the users name that uses the `"join"` command and add it to a field or something in a embed. I'm brand new and learning discord `API`.

Comment: The game will have all the players that joined names in a Embed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed()
  embed.add_field(name=f"{ctx.message.author.display_name}", value=f"has joined the game", inline=False)
  await client.say(embed=embed)


client.run('BOT_TOKEN')
```

Where you create an embed using `discord.Embed()` and add a field to it with the name of your user with `add_field()`
You can consult the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed) to see all the methods and properties you can use

Comment: Hello thank you very much for your feedback! After doing that i realized that i would like to start a embed and add onto one that already exists in a channel. something like i do a command like "start" and that would start a game a people are able to join. My guess is to make some sort of list with all players that have joined and continue to refresh the embed but im not sure how to turn that idea into code